# Why I am getting a one less count always

Tags: python, algorithm

I am solving a [**problem**](http://codeforces.com/contest/611/problem/B) in Codeforce and this was my previous submission

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

limit = 10**18
string = raw_input()
year1, year2 = string.split()
year1 = int(year1)
year2 = int(year2)
x = 1
count = 0
a = []
while True:
    k = 2**x - 1

    if k > limit:
        break
    else:
        for i in xrange(len(bin(k)[2:])):
            if year1 <= k - (1 << i) <= year2 and len(bin(k - (1 << i))[2:].split('0')) == 2:
                count += 1
    x += 1
print count
```

It worked for all the given values but it gave one less count value for the range `1` to `1000000000000000000`. It was hard to debug and hence I put a hacked up code before the last `print` like this

```
if year2 - year1 + 1 == limit:
    count += 1
```

and it worked for that value but again gave one less value value for another range, `1` to `935829385028502935`.

No wonder that the logic-less hack didn't work but I want to know that why it gave one less count value **previously ?**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but you do know that `range(b)` will yield the values `0` through `b-1` correct?

Comment: Yes I know that..and that is the intention..bit positions start with 0 index and run one less than maximum...one less count means one less count value than the actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to simplify code (it works now, Accepted):

```
limit = 10**19 # this change is important because otherwise you will loose 1 solution
# k > limit and exists such i that k - (1 << i) < limit

string = raw_input()
year1, year2 = string.split()
year1 = int(year1)
year2 = int(year2)
x = 1
count = 0
a = []
while True:
    k = 2**x - 1
    if k > limit:
        break

    for i in xrange(x - 1): # k has exactly x bits. So we have only x-1 chances to set zero bit
        if year1 <= k - (1 << i) <= year2:
            count += 1
    x += 1

print count
```

Submission: http://codeforces.com/contest/611/submission/15230069

Comment: Did this work? If so, say so in your answer. If not, delete it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to increase `limit` by another order of magnitude:

```
limit = 10**19
```

Otherwise you'd miss `864691128455135231`, obtained from `1152921504606846975 - (1 << 58)`.

(Observe that `1152921504606846975 > 10**18`.)